# ¿Puede usarse en PHP OOP una variable tipo array (compuesto) dentro de un método set y recuperar su valor con get?

Tags: php, poo

```
public function getActivo() {
            return $this->activo;
        }

public function setActivo() {
       $this->activo = ['caja' => 5000000,
                        'bancos' => 5000000,
                        'inventario' => 5000000,
                        'muebyequipo' => 5000000,
                        'local' => 10000000,
                        'vehic' => 20000000 ];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    class getActivo
    {
        public $activo ;

        public function __construct($activo )
        {
            $this->activo = $activo ;
        }

        public function __toString()
        {
            return $activo ->activo ;
        }
    }

    $abc = new getActivo('desde Get');
    echo $abc;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si declaras tu clase como:

```
<?php
class manejadorActivos {
    private $activo ;

    public function __construct() {
      return $this;
    }

    public function getActivo() { 
      return $this->activo; 
    }

    public function setActivo() { 
      $this->activo = [
         'caja' => 5000000, 
         'bancos' => 5000000, 
         'inventario' => 5000000, 
         'muebyequipo' => 5000000, 
         'local' => 10000000, 
         'vehic' => 20000000 
      ]; 
    }
}

$manejador = new manejadorActivos();
$manejador->setActivo();

var_dump($manejador->getActivo());
```

efectivamente puedes fijarle el valor que tú quieras a las propiedades de la clase.

Por el título de tu pregunta me entró la duda de si acaso querías usar los métodos mágicos `__get` y `__set` pero si no es el caso, sólo se prestaría para generar confusión